# scanning a sequence and outputting a sub sequence

Tags: text-processing

I am looking for a one liner for this if it is possible.
I have a sequence like this

```
CCGGTCTCTTCCGGTTCTGTCTTTTCGCTGG
```

I want to get the output where I scan the sequence base by base and then take 20 bp from that. SO the output should be something like this

```
CCGGTCTCTTCCGGTTCTGT
CGGTCTCTTCCGGTTCTGTC
GGTCTCTTCCGGTTCTGTCT
```

and so on..
The length should always be 20 bp

I wrote a perl code and it worked. Looking for one liner if some one can help using awk or sed??

```
while(<>){
    chomp;
    for my $i(0..length($_)){
        my $str = substr($_,$i,20);
        next if(length($str) < 20);
        print $str,"\n";
    }

}
```

Let me know

Comment: Is this a bunch of sequences in a file, or just one sequence?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're already familiar with Perl, why not use it? Perl excels at one-liners:

```
$ perl -F'' -lane 'for($i=0;$i<=$#F-20;$i++){print @F[$i..$i+20]}' file
CCGGTCTCTTCCGGTTCTGTC
CGGTCTCTTCCGGTTCTGTCT
GGTCTCTTCCGGTTCTGTCTT
GTCTCTTCCGGTTCTGTCTTT
TCTCTTCCGGTTCTGTCTTTT
CTCTTCCGGTTCTGTCTTTTC
TCTTCCGGTTCTGTCTTTTCG
CTTCCGGTTCTGTCTTTTCGC
TTCCGGTTCTGTCTTTTCGCT
TCCGGTTCTGTCTTTTCGCTG
CCGGTTCTGTCTTTTCGCTGG
```

#### Explanation

The `-a` switch makes `perl` act like `awk`, splitting its input lines on the value given by `-F` and saving them in `@F`. Since `-F` here is empty, the result is that the `@F` array's elements are the characters of the line.  The `-l` switch turns on `chomp` automatically and also adds a `\n` to each `print` call.

The script itself simply increments a counter (`$i`) from 0 until the length of the array (`$#F`) and does so as long as `$i` is less than or equal to the array's length minus 20, to only get sequences of the right size. It then prints the array slice from the current value of `$i` until `$i+20`.

If you run this with `-MO=Deparse` to analyze what its doing, you can see that it runs:

```
$ perl -MO=Deparse -F'' -lane 'for($i=0;$i<=$#F-20;$i++){print @F[$i..$i+20]}' file
BEGIN { $/ = "\n"; $\ = "\n"; }
LINE: while (defined($_ = <ARGV>)) {
    chomp $_;
    our @F = split(//, $_, 0);
    for ($i = 0; $i <= $#F - 20; ++$i) {
        print @F[$i .. $i + 20];
    }
}
-e syntax OK
```

Answer (score 3):

Assuming I understand you correctly, with `awk` this should be

```
awk -v s=CCGGTCTCTTCCGGTTCTGTCTTTTCGCTGG '
  BEGIN{while (length(x=substr(s, ++i, 20)) == 20) {print x} exit}'
```

> ```
> CCGGTCTCTTCCGGTTCTGT
> CGGTCTCTTCCGGTTCTGTC
> GGTCTCTTCCGGTTCTGTCT
> GTCTCTTCCGGTTCTGTCTT
> TCTCTTCCGGTTCTGTCTTT
> CTCTTCCGGTTCTGTCTTTT
> TCTTCCGGTTCTGTCTTTTC
> CTTCCGGTTCTGTCTTTTCG
> TTCCGGTTCTGTCTTTTCGC
> TCCGGTTCTGTCTTTTCGCT
> CCGGTTCTGTCTTTTCGCTG
> CGGTTCTGTCTTTTCGCTGG
> ```

Answer (score 3):

A `bash`-only version:

```
s=CCGGTCTCTTCCGGTTCTGTCTTTTCGCTGG
for ((i=0; i < ${#s} - 20; i++))
do 
  echo ${s:i:20}
done

CCGGTCTCTTCCGGTTCTGT
CGGTCTCTTCCGGTTCTGTC
GGTCTCTTCCGGTTCTGTCT
GTCTCTTCCGGTTCTGTCTT
TCTCTTCCGGTTCTGTCTTT
CTCTTCCGGTTCTGTCTTTT
TCTTCCGGTTCTGTCTTTTC
CTTCCGGTTCTGTCTTTTCG
TTCCGGTTCTGTCTTTTCGC
TCCGGTTCTGTCTTTTCGCT
CCGGTTCTGTCTTTTCGCTG
```

The loop takes an `i`ndex from zero until "length of s" minus 20, and prints 20 characters of "s" starting at that index.

Strictly in one line:

```
s=CCGGTCTCTTCCGGTTCTGTCTTTTCGCTGG; for ((i=0; i < ${#s} - 20; i++)); do echo ${s:i:20}; done
```

Answer (score 2):

```
sed -n '
  /.\{21,\}/ {
    h
    s/.//
    H
    x
  }
  s/\(.\{,20\}\).*\n/\1\n/
  P
  D
' <<< "CCGGTCTCTTCCGGTTCTGTCTTTTCGCTGG"
CCGGTCTCTTCCGGTTCTGT
CGGTCTCTTCCGGTTCTGTC
GGTCTCTTCCGGTTCTGTCT
GTCTCTTCCGGTTCTGTCTT
TCTCTTCCGGTTCTGTCTTT
CTCTTCCGGTTCTGTCTTTT
TCTTCCGGTTCTGTCTTTTC
CTTCCGGTTCTGTCTTTTCG
TTCCGGTTCTGTCTTTTCGC
TCCGGTTCTGTCTTTTCGCT
CCGGTTCTGTCTTTTCGCTG
CGGTTCTGTCTTTTCGCTGG
```

A 'one line' version might be

```
sed -n -e '/.\{21,\}/ {h;s/.//;H;x}' -e 's/\(.\{,20\}\).*\n/\1\n/' -e 'P;D' <<< "CCGGTCTCTTCCGGTTCTGTCTTTTCGCTGG"
```

or (slightly more readably, with extended syntax)

```
sed -nE -e '/.{21,}/ {h;s/.//;H;x}' -e 's/(.{,20}).*\n/\1\n/' -e 'P;D' <<< "CCGGTCTCTTCCGGTTCTGTCTTTTCGCTGG"
```

or if you're not religious about doing it all with sed

```
sed -nE \
  -e '/.{21,}/ {h;s/.//;H;x}' -e 'P;D' <<< "CCGGTCTCTTCCGGTTCTGTCTTTTCGCTGG" \
| cut -c-20
```

Answer (score 1):

```sh
sed -ne:20 -e's/./&\n/20;/\n/{P;s///;s/.//;}' -et20
```

That works with `sed`, if I get the question, that is.

---

```
CCGGTCTCTTCCGGTTCTGT
CGGTCTCTTCCGGTTCTGTC
GGTCTCTTCCGGTTCTGTCT
GTCTCTTCCGGTTCTGTCTT
TCTCTTCCGGTTCTGTCTTT
CTCTTCCGGTTCTGTCTTTT
TCTTCCGGTTCTGTCTTTTC
CTTCCGGTTCTGTCTTTTCG
TTCCGGTTCTGTCTTTTCGC
TCCGGTTCTGTCTTTTCGCT
CCGGTTCTGTCTTTTCGCTG
CGGTTCTGTCTTTTCGCTGG
```

It looks the same as everyone else's, though. It's pretty easy with `sed` - as long as there are at least 20 characters in its pattern space it will append a newline to the 20th, print up to the newline, then remove the newline and the first character before looping back over pattern space again.

With some `sed`'s you may need to use a literal newline in place of the `n` following the `&` replacement reference - and honestly that is the best way to do it, but it's harder to show that sort of stuff on a web page.